# scala list.par within an actor

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, akka

I tried to use list.par to achieve parallelism to do something within an actor. Something like below

```
MyActor {
     myList.par.map {
          listItem => doSomething(listItem)
     }
}
```

I think this has caused MyActor actors to lock themselves since I have spawned new threads with that list.par.map call. I figure creating other child actors for this parallelism work instead of list.par is the right way to go. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: use actors if and only if it's necessary otherwise actors can be a mess for your application. so unless you can tell me what kind of operation you are trying to do in the actor it's tough to tell you what is the problem.

Comment: That doSomething method can be a long running operation. What I am trying to achieve is to start that long running operation on all list items at once.

Comment: are they CPU bound operations or they are IO? and what kind of calls you are doing to the actor tell, ask which pattern you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by "actors lock themselves"? Does your whole system "lock up" or just the actor blocks further message processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documenation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/futures.html#within-actors):

> Each actor is configured to be run on a MessageDispatcher, and that
>   dispatcher doubles as an ExecutionContext. If the nature of the Future
>   calls invoked by the actor matches or is compatible with the
>   activities of that actor (e.g. all CPU bound and no latency
>   requirements), then it may be easiest to reuse the dispatcher for
>   running the Futures by importing context.dispatcher.

```
class A extends Actor {
  import context.dispatcher
  val f = Future("hello")
  def receive = {
    case _ ⇒
  }
}
```